# How to extract value of SOAP request attribute with including tags in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui

I'm creating mock SOAP-response which should return data contained in SOAP-request in SOAPUI.
Below is my SOAP REquest

```
<urn:BlockStatus>
            <urn1:Comment>COOOMMMENT</urn1:Comment>
            <urn1:IsBlocked>TRUE</urn1:IsBlocked>
            <urn1:Reason>REASSONNNN</urn1:Reason>
         </urn:BlockStatus>
```

I want to extract value of the BlockStatus tags (i.e All child xml under BlockStatus)

I tried below script

```
log.info xml.Body.Modify.BlockStatus
```

But it prints only value part of the childNodes not complete child xml

> **Actual Output :**  COOOMMMTRUEREASSONNNN
>
> **Expected Output :**
>
> ```
> <urn1:Comment>COOOMMMENT</urn1:Comment>
>             <urn1:IsBlocked>TRUE</urn1:IsBlocked>
>             <urn1:Reason>REASSONNNN</urn1:Reason>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for asserting your response ? if you are you can use xpath match assertion
first you will need to declare your `namespace` since your response contains one (urn) in xpath match window, you can use declare button for that.
Then you can add the following line: 
   `//urn:BlockStatus`